# Cannot receive from client socket in a loop

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple quiz between client and server. The server sends an array of questions and waits for a reply from client. The problem is that the client side does not display the array from server nor can take any input. The server has definitely connected to the client, but the client side stays idle.

Server:

```
OutputStream o =sock.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(o);
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
int i=0;
while(i<10)
{
 pw.println(array[i]);
 String st = br.readLine();
 System.out.println(st);
 i++;
}
```

Client:

```
InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
BufferedReader content = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
String str;
OutputStream ostream=sock.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ostream)
String ans;
for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    str=content.readLine();
    System.out.println(str);
    ans=sc.nextLine();
    pw.println(ans);
}
```

Comment: Does the client display anything at all? You tell us what doesn't happen but not what does happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PrintWriter#println` doesn't flush text to client by default so you need to call `pw.flush()` manually each time you want to ensure sending.

To let `println` automatically flush text to client use [`PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-boolean-) constructor with `autoFlush` parameter set as `true`, like

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(o, true);
```

since `PrintWriter(OutputStream out)` constructor internally invokes `this(out, false);` so automatic flash is disabled `println`, `printf` or `format` methods.

Comment: thanks! i enabled the autoflush in both server and client, now it works

Answer (score 0):

PrintWriter doesn't flush information itself by default. 
You should either add: `pw.flush()` after `pw.println(ans)` or create your writer in that way: `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(o, true);`